# Adding a formula to a cell. Getting 1004 error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a formula to cells to create hyperlinks that will jump between worksheets.

I get

> VBA Runtime Error 1004 Application-defined or Object-defined error

due to the `=` sign at the beginning of the string.

```vb
Public strcelladdress As String
Public hyperlink1 As String
Public hyperlink2 As String
Public hyperlinkfinal As String
Public columnletter As String
Public rngTarget As Range
Public ADVICErow As Integer
Public CALLrow As Integer
Public TSHOOTcol As Integer

columnletter = Split(Worksheets("Troubleshooting Advice").Cells(ADVICErow, 1).Address, "$")(1)
columnletter = Right(columnletter, 1)
strcelladdress = columnletter + CStr(ADVICErow)
hyperlink1 = "HYPERLINK(""#'Troubleshooting Advice'!"
hyperlink2 = ",""Link to Troubleshooting Advice"")"
hyperlinkfinal = hyperlink1 + strcelladdress + hyperlink2
Set rngTarget = Worksheets("Call Examples").Cells(CALLrow, TSHOOTcol)
rngTarget.Formula = "=" + hyperlinkfinal
```

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/hyperlink-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f

Comment: Check your syntax: Debug.Print hyperlinkfinal

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using global public variables. Let's not do that if we can avoid it.

Always use `&` to concatenate strings in VBA. Only use `+` for math. That way it's clear to everybody what you are trying to do.

You hard code a 1 in your `.cells` equation to get the columnletter, which is odd because you could just declare "A" instead.

Let's use the HyperLink VBA object model instead of cell formula.

NOTE: I can't fully test my code outside of your spreadsheet.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddFormulaToCell()
    Dim strcelladdress As String
    Dim hyperlink1 As String
    Dim hyperlink2 As String
    Dim hyperlinkfinal As String
    Dim columnletter As String
    Dim rngTarget As Range
    Dim ADVICErow As Integer
    Dim CALLrow As Integer
    Dim TSHOOTcol As Integer

    'columnletter = Split(Worksheets("Troubleshooting Advice").Cells(ADVICErow, 1).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
    'columnletter = Right$(columnletter, 1)
    columnletter = "A"
    strcelladdress = columnletter + CStr(ADVICErow)
    hyperlink1 = """#'Troubleshooting Advice'!" & strcelladdress & """"
    hyperlink2 = "Link to Troubleshooting Advice"
    With Worksheets("Call Examples")
        .Hyperlink.Add Anchor:=.Cells(CALLrow, TSHOOTcol), _
            Address:=hyperlink1, _
            ScreenTip:=hyperlink2, _
            TextToDisplay:=hyperlink2
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried using & instead of + and it now puts a ' before the = sign to make it text instead of a formula. I changed the cell's format for numbers from Text to General, and started getting the error again. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I gave you an example of how to approach this problem a little differently.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This ultimately led to a solution. I will post what worked for me in an answer. I am new to Excel VBA so most of my code is cobbled together.

Comment: All the thanks I need is an upvote. Click the little up arrow on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Here was the code that ended up working for me:

```
Sub AddHyperlinkA()

Dim targetsheet As String
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Call Examples")
targetsheet = "Troubleshooting Advice"

    columnletter = "A"
    strcelladdress = columnletter + CStr(ADVICErowtarget)
    hyperlink1 = "'" & targetsheet & "'!" & strcelladdress
    hyperlink2 = "Link to Troubleshooting Advice"
    With sht
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(CALLrow, TSHOOTcol), _
            Address:="", _
            SubAddress:=hyperlink1, _
            ScreenTip:=hyperlink2, _
            TextToDisplay:=hyperlink2
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If this is the answer you can close out the question by clicking the green checkmark. That way, people know the question is answered and where the answer is.